# Trezor - Can a hacker rebuild my wallet with my RECOVERY SEED without my Trezor PASSPHRASE?

Tags: seed, passphrase, trezor, hacking

I know a hacker could rebuild my wallet on another trezor or compatible hot wallet with my recovery seedphrase.  This would get them to the ROOT of my original account.
But what if I had a PASSPHRASE also?
I assume they would need to know it as well to get to that account.

Also, if they knew the passphrase as well - would they need a physical Trezor to access the account?

Comment: Yes they can rebuild your Trezor exactly as it was as the passphrase is never stored on the Trezor. And no, they would not need the Trezor if they have the words since the words can be used on many different wallets as its as standard Bitcoin system to create addresses. If you have a passphrase, thats an extra layer of security but with the 24 words its easy to brake a passphrase if less than 8 characters. So considering using a long and complicated passphrase not found in a dictionary or a password library like the rockyou.txt

Answer (score 0):

> **Can a hacker rebuild my wallet with my RECOVERY SEED without my Trezor PASSPHRASE?**

According to [a Trezor blog article](https://blog.trezor.io/5-reasons-why-you-should-use-a-passphrase-and-3-reasons-why-you-maybe-shouldnt-411c3935ac81)

> Even if someone steals your recovery seed, they still wouldn’t be able to steal your crypto if you use a passphrase.

Comment: Please note that passphrase can be brute-forced. If you use "Password1" as a passphrase, guessing such passphrase won't take much time.
So choose random and long-enough one.